# Change Video (Different quality) file in html5 through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Moto: Change being played video, when user click a button, through Jquery. 
sample website: http://sublimevideo.net (on click "hd" button in the player control)

In detail:

On page load, browser will play first video given in source (url: "The-Dark.mp4"). What I want is, when user click HD button (control), the browser should play the next (url: "The-Dark-hd.mp4")

Its my HTML code:

```
        <source src="asserts/The-Dark.mp4" type="video/mp4;" data-quality="sd"></source>            
        <source src="asserts/The-Dark-hd.mp4" type="video/mp4;" codecs="&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" data-quality="hd"></source>

        <source src="asserts/The-Dark.ogg" type="video/ogg;" codecs="&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;"></source>

        <source src="asserts/The-Dark-hd.ogg" type="video/ogg;" codecs="&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;"></source>
</video>
```

Please let me know the Jquery which I need to follow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('source', 'video')​​.eq(1).prependTo('video');
$('video')[0].load();
$('video')[0].play();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bY9mH/)

Comment: thanks a lot "Adeneo".
it works fine.
I'm sorry to ask. May you please explain the code?
I'm absolute beginner for JQuery and this is my very first API Development

Comment: The first line gets the second source tag, and moves it up to be the first source tag, as that is what is used by the video tag. Then `$('video')[0]` gets the plain javascript DOM element, and could be written `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]` as well, and we need the DOM element as `load()` and `play()` are not jQuery methods but plain javascript methods, and calling `load()` reloads the video with the first valid source, which is now what used to be the second source, and then calling `play()` starts the newly loaded video again.